# How can we connect PHP to Unix?

Tags: php, unix, module

I am using Unix on telnet/ssh on a network with several modules and DBs. I need to my PHP layer to connect to any of them when the particular user from the particular module tries to connect...

Is there a way to universally connect to UNIX?

Comment: yeah, you just mentioned it, it's `ssh`.

Comment: Either you really aren't expressing yourself well or you've got a problem understanding the how your system is structured.  Do you mean is there a standard DB connection protocol?

Comment: well ya... im a newbie in these 'connection' problems. Forget bout the whole thing... basically i want to execute UNIX commands through PHP...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your latest comment... If you want to execute shell commands through PHP, try [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) or [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [passthru](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) or [popen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php). They each do slightly different things.

Comment: ... and since you can execute shell commands you can also call `ssh [user@]hostname [command]`. you have to set up ssh keys to execute command without authentication though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to connect using PHP language :

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, '/usr/local/bin/php -i');
?>
// $connection is the SSH connection link identifier, obtained from a call to ssh2_connect().
```